# Taking the steady state of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, steady-state

I'm finding the steady state of this matrix
\begin{bmatrix}0&1/3&0&1/4\\1/2&0&1/3&1/4\\0&1/3&0&1/2\\1/2&1/3&2/3&0\end{bmatrix}
I know I first have to solve
$\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I) = 0$.
So I know that I need to find the determinant of

\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda&1/3&0&1/4\\1/2&-\lambda&1/3&1/4\\0&1/3&-\lambda&1/2\\1/2&1/3&2/3&-\lambda\end{bmatrix}

When I took the determinant I got $\lambda^4-59/72\lambda^2-7/36\lambda+1/72$.
When I set that equal to zero I got $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = .0575$

But when I tried to plug those into the matrix above and solve for the null space I only got the trivial solution. I don't know what that means for the steady-state, or even what to do next. I was thinking that the only answer being the trivial solution means that the steady-state maybe whatever the original distribution was.

edit:
when $\lambda = 1$ the eigenvector is \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\3/4\\3/4\\1\end{bmatrix}
dividing by three I get
\begin{bmatrix}1/6\\1/4\\1/4\\1/3\end{bmatrix}
which I believe to be my final answer.

Comment: The steady state is the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$,  You should get a nontrivial solution for this.

Comment: Does that mean that I would be right to assume the steady-state is whatever the original distribution was? Because the eigenspace for  = 1 consists of only the zero vector.

Comment: No, there is a non-trivial solution here.   Check your work.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that the eigenspace for   = 1 isn't the zero vector. I messed up my row operations.

Comment: Your matrix has $4$ eigenvalues:
$$1,\ -\frac{1}{3},\ \frac{-4\pm\sqrt{22}}{12}.$$
The eigenvectors for the first two eigenvalues are
$$
(1,1,1,1)^T,\ (1, -5/3, -1/3, 1)^T.
$$